# CString::find... iterative use issue?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, find

I'm using a CString to search a text block... here's my code:

```
// locate file name in dir listing
in = *buf;
i = in.Find("DOWNLD  .DAT  ");// find start of name, two spaces (0x20) as delim
                    // size of search text here is 14
if (i == -1) return 0;

j = in.Find(' ',i);// now find next space char *after* file size... 
        // why don't I have to add to i here? There are spaces in my search string.

if (j == -1) return 0;

fileSize = in.Mid((i+14),j-i);// extract file size string, note indexing past found string

return atoi(fileSize.GetBuffer());
```

Here's what MSDN has to say about the return value of find:
" Return Value
The zero-based index of the first character in this CString object that matches the requested substring or characters; -1 if the substring or character is not found."

Now the way I read this, I have to index past the string I found before doing another find... but the way it actually works, I use the 'i' returned before as the start position for a new search.  I'm using this in other places in my program, and I definitely have to index past it (when using ::mid(), for instance)... I'd like to know why this is happening, if by design or bug.  The original string can be large; I've seen it near 300chars... is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your second `Find` call finds the space after "DOWNLD", not the one after ".DAT  ". You want to increment `i` before the second `Find` call, so that it refers to the first character **past** the string your first call searched for.

Comment: I didn't make it clear... the current code works fine.  I started by doing as you suggest... it didn't work.  Via debugging and hard work I found as I said... the index, when used the second time, points *past* the found string, not to the beginning... it doesn't stop where you said, it finds the file size.  Thanks for trying, anyway.

Comment: That makes no sense. Are you saying that, after `i = in.Find("DOWNLD  .DAT  ");`, you discover that `in[i] != 'D'`? With all due respect, I would find that very hard to believe.

Comment: Just to be more clear... the mid requires the index to be incremented.  The i returned points where it's supposed to, as used by mid.  It's the second call to Find using the same string that does the funny stuff, I tried j=in.Find(' ',(i+14)), no go, it returned the rest of the directory listing 14 past the *end* of the first search string, until it hit a space.  I think it's a bug... I'll try the version that searches for a substring instead of the version that searches for a char and get back to y'all.

Comment: Define "no go". Exactly what happens with `j=in.Find(' ',(i+14));`? How does the result differ from your expectations? Also, in `in.Mid((i+14),j-i);`, the second parameter should be `j-i-14`. Better still, just do `i += 14;` right after the first `Find()` (if successful), and drop all other adjustments.

Comment: OK, I found the error... I'll post the answer in 51 minutes when SO allows.

Comment: it's just as Igor said, really.  I happened to find it just as he replied.\

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't find a bug in CString... my code was in error.  Here's the code changed that works:

```
    j = in.Find(' ',i+14);// index past searched string 

if (j == -1) return 0;

fileSize = in.Mid((i+14),j-i-14);// note -14 added

return atoi(fileSize.GetBuffer());
```

It was the missing -14 in the mid that was confusing me... the resulting string was 14 past where it should have been, and was missing the portion of interest.  Why my original fix worked?  Just a coincidence I guess.

Thanks for helping!